# access control for assets in a website powered by wordpress

Tags: pages, user-access

My organization has a website powered by wordpress. We are using pagebuilder to design pages. We also have some assets (pdf files, ppts) etc. Currently everyone can access these files.

I need to modify them so that there is some access control. So the first suggestion to provide the access control was “register” each user that wants to access the files. Based on the type of user (normal, HR, Finance etc) each of them can have access to a specific set of files.

Could anyone suggest how the above can be done.

Answer (score 1):

You dont say if the files are downloadable only, but..
I recently had a similar situation where whilst running a real estate site and giving access to contract,inventories etc was a need between the client and landlord, giving only access to these whilst relative to the post(property) in question.

I ended up with what I think was the quickest and most robust choice by installing the Wordpress Download manager [Download Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/download-manager/).
Using it you can then set up a function in the relative page giving access to the shortcodes by user role.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manage users in groups by department, and control the content that they see, it seems that a members plugin might be a better fit.

[This one](http://themehybrid.com/plugins/members) by Justin Tadlock has been around **and maintained** for a long time.

It allows you to set up custom users roles. In addition to the the usual Administrator, Editor, etc. You could add roles like HR, Finance, or normal (that's a nice distinction btw, I'm neither finance or HR, so I guess that makes me normal :) ). The plugin even allow you to assign multiple roles, so you could retain Admin priveledges, but also be a part of HR and have access to that content.

On your pages, you can control who sees what content with shortcode. This should work fine with your page builder, and would work with the Download Manager suggested above. Download manager will track how many downloads a certain file gets. If you need to know that that's helpful. It also allows you to set passwords for specific files if you need to have that level of control.